# hapi fhir server full turn key implementation

Tags: hapi-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

So I have been using Hapi Fhir Server (for several years) as a way to expose proprietary data in my company....aka, implementing IResourceProvider for several resources.
Think "read only" in this world.

Now I am considering accepting writes.

The Hapi Fhir Server has this exert:

> JPA Server
>
> The HAPI FHIR RestfulServer module can be used to create a FHIR server
>   endpoint against an arbitrary data source, which could be a database
>   of your own design, an existing clinical system, a set of files, or
>   anything else you come up with.
>
> HAPI also provides a persistence module which can be used to provide a
>   complete RESTful server implementation, backed by a database of your
>   choosing. This module uses the JPA 2.0 API to store data in a database
>   without depending on any specific database technology.
>
> Important Note: This implementation uses a fairly simple table design,
>   with a single table being used to hold resource bodies (which are
>   stored as CLOBs, optionally GZipped to save space) and a set of tables
>   to hold search indexes, tags, history details, etc. This design is
>   only one of many possible ways of designing a FHIR server so it is
>   worth considering whether it is appropriate for the problem you are
>   trying to solve.

http://hapifhir.io/doc_jpa.html

So I did this download (of the jpa server) and got it working against a real db-engine (overriding the default jpa definition).....and I observed the "fairly simple table design".  So I am thankful for this simple demo.  But looking at the simple, it does concern me for a full blown production setup.

If I wanted to setup a Fhir Server, are there any "non trivial" (where above says "fairly simple table design") ... to implement a robust fhir server...
that supports versioning (history) of the resources, validation of "references (example, if someone uploads an Encounter, it checks the Patient(reference) and the Practitioner(reference) in the Encounter payload......etc, etc?
And that is using a robust nosql database?

Or am I on the hook for implementing a non-trivial nosql database?
Or did I go down the wrong path with JPA?

I'm ok with starting from "scratch" (an empty data-store for my fhir-server)....and if I had to import any data, I understand what that would entail.

Thanks.

Another way to ask this.....is......is there a hapi-fhir way to emulate this library: (please don't regress into holy-war issues between java and dotnet)

But below is more what I would consider a "full turn key" solution.  Using NoSql (CosmoDB).

https://github.com/Microsoft/fhir-server

> A .NET Core implementation of the FHIR standard.
>
> FHIR Server for Azure is an open-source implementation of the
>   emerging HL7 Fast Healthcare Interoperability Resources (FHIR)
>   specification designed for the Microsoft cloud. The FHIR specification
>   defines how clinical health data can be made interoperable across
>   systems, and the FHIR Server for Azure helps facilitate that
>   interoperability in the cloud. The goal of this Microsoft Healthcare
>   project is to enable developers to rapidly deploy a FHIR service.
>
> With data in the FHIR format, the FHIR Server for Azure enables
>   developers to quickly ingest and manage FHIR datasets in the cloud,
>   track and manage data access and normalize data for machine learning
>   workloads. FHIR Server for Azure is optimized for the Azure ecosystem:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any implementation of the HAPI server which support a full persistence layer in NoSQL.

HAPI has been around for a while, the persistence layer has evolved quite a bit and seems to be appropriate for many production scenarios, especially when backed by a performant relational database.

The team that maintains HAPI also uses it as the basis for a commercial offering, [Smile CDR](https://smilecdr.com/open-source.html).  Many of the enhancements that went into making Smile CDR production ready are baked into the HAPI open source project.  There has also been some discussion on [scaling the JPA implementation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hapi-fhir/yNCsibiBK80).

If you're serious about using HAPI in production I'd recommend doing some benchmarks on the demo server you set up that simulate some of your production use-cases to see if it will get you what you want, you may be surprised.  You can also contact the folks at Smile CDR as they do consulting and could likely tell you more specifically how to tune an instance to scale for your production priorities.

Comment: Thanks for information.  Marking this as the answer since its been hanging out for a bit.  Your clues helped me understand better.  Thanks cmike.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firely's implementation of FHIR. The most used repo is the FHIR SDK;

https://github.com/FirelyTeam/firely-net-sdk

But if you want more done for you out of the box you can use their Spark repo. This uses the SDK underneath and ultimately gives you a IAsyncFhirService which you can use for CRUD operations;

https://github.com/FirelyTeam/spark

And to your question; Spark currently only supports Mongo DB as the data persistence layer i.e. there is no entity like mapping done to create a db schema in a relational database. NoSQL I think made sense in this case.

Alternatively, check out the list of FHIR implementations in other languages maintained by HL7 themselves;

https://wiki.hl7.org/Open_Source_FHIR_implementations